# Ready configurations for Spring + Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, project-template

Sometimes, it's very tediously to make own configuration, find all libraries, check it ...
So, is there any ready typical (template) config for appropriative task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[AppFuse](http://appfuse.org) can be used for generating project templates for your given choice and combination of technologies.

Answer (score 3):

[Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/roo) is designed for this.  It's on RC2 for their 1.0 release now.

It has a command shell environment that allows you to pick and setup the parts of the Spring application you'd like to use.  It generates the Spring config files, Maven setup, and templates the Java classes for you.

Besides being great for templating, it's also a good way to get yourself introduced to other parts of the Spring application stack (Web Flow, Security).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you'll find what you're looking for here: http://code.google.com/p/project-template/.

Answer (score 0):

There is no ready made runtime config for your application but you can use things like [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) or [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) to manage all the JARs you need automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You could start from one of the examples as provided in the Spring download package and modify it to suits your need.